# undefined method `close_connection_after_writing'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comet, faye

I have project on rails 3 with multiplayer using Faye.
The error

> `block in close': undefined method`close_connection_after_writing' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

```
from /Users/ostap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@chats/gems/faye-websocket-0.4.5/lib/faye/websocket/api.rb:89:in `call'
    from /Users/ostap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@chats/gems/faye-websocket-0.4.5/lib/faye/websocket/api.rb:89:in `close'
    from /Users/ostap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@chats/gems/faye-websocket-0.4.5/lib/faye/websocket.rb:198:in `fail'
    from /Users/ostap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:155:in `unbind'
    from /Users/ostap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:1417:in `event_callback'
    from /Users/ostap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
    from /Users/ostap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
    from /Users/ostap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:61:in `start'
    from /Users/ostap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
    from /Users/ostap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
    from /Users/ostap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
    from /Users/ostap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:137:in `start'
    from /Users/ostap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rack-1.4.1/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ostap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@chats/bin/rackup:19:in `load'
    from /Users/ostap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@chats/bin/rackup:19:in `<main>'
```

after my faye server startup with command

> rackup faye.ru -s thin -E production

What can I do with such error?? What couses it? How can I handle it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i found on this page (it's in russian) http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/45416/

add this to your faye.ru file

Faye::WebSocket.load_adapter('thin')

this made my solution

i hope it helps an thanks for the advice

Comment: Yes)) I wrote that post on Habr after this) when I had known the solution. Was that post on Habr useful?

Comment: Yes indeed, it was the thing which brought me to a nice day ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this issue after upgrading faye.

To build on @tingel2k's answer, you need to insert this:

```
Faye::WebSocket.load_adapter('thin')
```

into `faye.ru` before the app is started, eg:

```
run Faye::RackAdapter.new(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

do not use `rackup` to start faye
instead, use `thin start -R faye.ru -e production`
this is my faye.ru file

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'faye'
require File.expand_path('../config/initializers/faye_token.rb', __FILE__)

Faye::WebSocket.load_adapter('thin')

class ServerAuth
  def incoming(message, callback)
    if message['channel'] !~ %r{^/meta/}
      if message['ext']['auth_token'] != FAYE_TOKEN
        message['error'] = 'Token de autenticacao invalido'
      end
    end
    callback.call(message)
  end
end

bayeux = Faye::RackAdapter.new(:mount => '/faye', :timeout => 25, :extensions => [ServerAuth.new])
run bayeux
```

Answer (score 0):

This is EventMachine error. This method receiver is a connection object, so i think that this error means that connection was terminated in not proper way or wasn't created.